# Help! My jQuery accordion just broke up. how to fix it?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

I just can't sort out why my kaccordion on wordpress broke up... the console says that jquery "filter" is not defined.
does anybody know what does it mean?
the exact error is:

> jQuery.filter(expr, [i]).r is undefined

the domain is:

http://www.tunnel-milano.it/

I need help in debugging it, don't know where to start: how can "filter" function be "not defined"??
thank you!

edit:
here's the code I'm using:

$('dl.Kaccordion').each(function(i) {
    $(this).Accordion({
        active: false,
        alwaysOpen: false,
        header: 'dt.toggle',
        selectedClass: "active",
        showSpeed: "fast",
        hideSpeed: "fast"
    });
});

Comment: Please use a non-minified version of your code for debugging and error reports.

Comment: Or at least indicate where in your code you initiate the accordian so we do not have to decipher the whole page ;)

Comment: It's a wordpress plugin... I only have it in its compressed version unfortunately. I'll try to find the source, expanded, code! sorry!

Answer (score 1):

It just turned out that the jQuery version loaded by Wordpress was not compatible with the jQuery from the plugin (Kaccordion) so I stopped wordpress from loading jQuery in the wp_head with this code:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_head();
```

thank you all, anyways!